# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'module' and 'LinearSegmentedColormap'

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, svm

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as cmap

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)

print(len(digits.data))

x, y = digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1]
clf.fit(x,y)

print('Prediction:', clf.predict(digits.data[[-1]]))

plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap-plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation-"nearest")
plt.show()
```

when running this code in python 3.8.3, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aben\Downloads\pythonstuff\machinelearning.py", line 18, in <module>
    plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap-plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation-"nearest")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'module' and 'LinearSegmentedColormap'
```

anyone know why?
I'm using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTeVOb8gaD4&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDd0flgGphKCej-9jp-QdzZ3&index=2) tutorial btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you have `-` instead of `=` when passing arguments to `imshow()`. Fix it like that:

```py
plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation="nearest")
```